# If the value of this improper integral is positive, then can one say that the integrand is positive almost everywhere?

Tags: integration

I have a real valued continuous function $f(t)$ over the real line such that,
$$\int\limits_0^\infty{f(t)\,ds}\geq 0.$$
Then can it be concluded that the,
$$\int\limits_0^t{f(s)\,ds}\geq 0, \quad \forall t>0?$$

My attempt at an answer.

Since $$\int\limits_0^\infty{f(t)\,ds}\geq 0,$$ and $f(t)$ is continuous, I conjecture that, $f(t)$ is positive a.e. on $[0,\infty).$ Then clearly, $f(t)$ is positive a.e. on $[0,t]$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}.$ This implies that, $$\int\limits_0^t{f(s)\,ds}\geq 0, \quad \forall t>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

A simple counterexample:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\cos x  & \text{if $x\le\frac{3\pi}{2}$} \\
0 & \text{if $x>\frac{3\pi}{2}$}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if } 0<x<1, \\ 2e^{-(x-1)} & \text{if } x>1. \end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx = -1 \text{ and } \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = +1.
$$

Comment: $f$ is supposed to be continuous.